# Make the "LOGGER" logger private static final error is thrown for interface in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

By default Java Interface doesn't allow private static final members. But in SonarQube, Make the "LOGGER" logger private static final error is thrown for interface.

Any specific reason for this?

Example:

```
public interface UserPropUtil {

    static final Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger(UserPropUtil.class.getName());

    static String getUserProp(String key, String defaultValue) {
        Userprop toReturn=null;
        try {
            toReturn= getUserProp(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide a code example, and a link to the rule you are violating

Comment: Why would you put the logger in an interface in the first place.

Comment: @Kayaman In Java 8 we can add static implementation in interface. So we need to add it.

Comment: The idea of putting a logger on an `interface` makes me somewhat queezy. When I implemnet an `interface` and inherit from a parent `class`, and that parent implements a couple of `interface`; in your glorious scheme, what logger do I use?

Comment: If you are adding so much default logic to an `interface` that you need a logger, you are adding far too much logic... But you can always add a `getLogger` method for the implementor to return _its_ logger.

Comment: To your example - this defines no contract. It is not an `interface`. It is a utility `class` - don't abuse inheritance. This is no better, actually worse, that the Constant Interface Antipattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just pasted a part of the code. This is not the complete code.

Comment: Also, it's an awful method. If it fails to find the property it returns `null` and logs an error? Methods should return what they mean, not log what they mean. How do I, as a caller to this method, know what happened? In short - lose the logger and throw a sesible exception. Also never catch `Exception`.